# VBA - using a wild card in filename to avoid processing a file

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping though a number of directories in VBA and am trying to avoid processing one file in each directory.  The first two letters of the filename changes depending on the directory I am searching.

So for example in one directory the file would be called EE-Help-Me.xlsx and in another it would be called F-Help-Me.xlsx. I have tried to use the wildcard *-Help-Me but have obviously done something wrong as the file is processed. How can I fix this?

My code is:

```
Sub ListFiles(fld As Object, Mask As String)
Dim fl As Object 'File
For Each fl In fld.Files
    If fl.Name Like Mask Then
    'open and interrogate file here

       If fl.Name <> "*-Help-Me.xlsx" Then '<<-- not catching when the offending file is present
            Debug.Print fld.Path & "\" & fl.Name
            'Do something
       End If


    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
If Not fl.Name Like "*-Help-Me.xlsx" Then
```